# FB JS SDK - How to check whether any user has logged in for the first time

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm using this function as event handler for my onclick event and it is working fine -

```
var facebookLogin = function() {
  checkLoginState(function(data) {
    if (data.status !== 'connected') {
      FB.login(function(response) {
        if (response.status === 'connected') 
          // I do what I want to do here if login is succesful.
      }, {scope: scopes});
    }
  })
}
```

But is there a way so that I can get to know that the user has logged in for the first time so that I can save him into my database or perform certain actions?

Answer (score 0):

Every time a user logs in, get the Facebook ID with the `getId()` method.

If the ID does not exist in your database, add his information to your database, if it does, you know what he has logged in before.